# AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, resultset, findall

Where is error? I want to parse my text without tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup       
import re
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.championat.com/football/news-2442480-orlov-zenit-obespokoen---pole-na-novom-stadione-mozhet-byt-nekachestvennym.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

soup=soup.find_all('div', class_="text-decor article__contain")

invalid_tags = ['b', 'i', 'u', 'br', 'a']

for tag in invalid_tags: 

  for match in soup.find_all(tag):

        match.replaceWithChildren()

soup = ''.join(map(str, soup.contents))

print (soup)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
    for match in soup.find_all(tag):
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: You replaced `soup` with a resultset: `soup=soup.find_all('div', class_="text-decor article__contain")`. A resulset is simply a list with an extra reference back to the original soup object. It is not clear to me why you are replacing the `BeautifulSoup` object with a resultset, if you wanted to do a nested search use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead.

Comment: You really want to look at [output formatting](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output) too, don't map the objects to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `soup=soup.find_all('div', class_="text-decor article__contain")`

On this line `soup` becomes a `ResultSet` instance - basically a *list of `Tag` instances*. And, you are getting the `'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'` since this `ResultSet` instance does not have a `find_all()` method. FYI, this problem is actually described in the [troubleshooting section](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous) in the docs:

> `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This
>   usually happens because you expected `find_all()` to return a single tag
>   or string. But `find_all()` returns a *list* of tags and strings–a
>   ResultSet object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the
>   .foo of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to
>   use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

And you really want one result, since there is a single article on the page:

```
soup = soup.find('div', class_="text-decor article__contain")
```

Note though that there is no need to find tags one by one, you can pass a list of tag names directly to `find_all()` - `BeautifulSoup` is quite flexible in locating elements:

```
article = soup.find('div', class_="text-decor article__contain")

invalid_tags = ['b', 'i', 'u', 'br', 'a']
for match in article.find_all(invalid_tags):
     match.unwrap()  # bs4 alternative for replaceWithChildren
```